# Querying from an API to a Google Spreadsheet / G Apps Script and obtaining filtered results

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, forex

I'm trying to build a spreadsheet based around [DataDT's](http://www.datadt.com/) excellent API for 1-minute Forex data. I'm trying to build a function that 1) Reads a value ("Date time") from a cell 2) Searches for that value in a given URL from the aforementioned API 3) Prints 2 other properties (open & close price) for that same date.

[image: Current spreadsheet status]

In other words, It would take input from rows N and O, and output the relevant values (OPEN and CLOSE from the API) in rows H and I.

(Link to current [GSpreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13LpVv_GGHtV6myKdFJUrWUNGepDP_zylIuzmC_frt7k/edit#gid=2026708527))

This spreadsheet would link macroeconomic news and historic prices and possibly reveal useful insights for Forex users.

I already managed to query data from the API effectively but I can't find a way to filter only for the datetimes I'm asking. Much less iterating for different dates! With the help from user @Cooper I got the following code that can query entire pages from the API but can't efficiently filter yet. I'd appreciate any help that you might provide.

This is the current status of the code in Appscript:

(Code.gs)

```
function searchOnEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');// I use these lines for debugging
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='API') return;
  var checkedValue='TRUE';//these are the defaults if you install the checkboxes from the Insert Menu
  var uncheckedValue='FALSE';
  if(e.range.columnStart==17 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value==checkedValue) {
    e.range.setValue(uncheckedValue);//this was commented out it should not have been sorry for that Cooper
    //e.source.toast('flag1');
    var r=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var obj={datetime:r[14],url:r[13],event:e};
    var dObj=getDataDT1(obj);
    //Logger.log(dObj);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).setValue(dObj.OPEN);//loading OPEN on your spreadsheet
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,5).setValue(dObj.CLOSE);//loadding CLOSE on your spreadsheet
  }
}

//{datetime:'',url:'',event:e}
function getDataDT1(obj) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj));//I need to see this
  var r=UrlFetchApp.fetch(obj.url);
  var data=JSON.parse(r.getContentText("UTF-8"));
  //Logger.log(data);
  var pair='USDJPY';
  var dat=new Date(obj.datetime);
  var dtv=new Date(dat.getFullYear(),dat.getMonth(),dat.getDate(),dat.getHours(),dat.getMinutes()).valueOf();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var dt=data[i].DATE_TIME.split(' ');
    var sd=new Date(data[i].DATE_TIME);
    var sdv=new Date(sd.getFullYear(),sd.getMonth(),sd.getDate(),sd.getHours(),sd.getMinutes()).valueOf();
    if(sdv==dtv) {
      var d=dt[0].split('-');
      var t=dt[1].split(':');
      var datestring=Utilities.formatString('%s/%s/%s',d[1],d[2],d[0]);
      var timestring=Utilities.formatString('%s:%s',t[0],t[1]);
      var rObj={DATE:datestring,TIME:timestring,PAIR:pair,OPEN:data[i].OPEN.toFixed(3),CLOSE:data[i].CLOSE.toFixed(3)};
      break;
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(rObj);
  return rObj;
}
```

(Appscript.json)

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Caracas",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes":  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
}
```

(Trigger.js)

```
function createSearchOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('searchOnEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```

Comment: Okay since I already know what you are trying to do,  the question is where to I get the datetime from and what format will it be in.  And can you provide an image of your spreadsheet. Show where the results need to be placed.

Comment: Sure! I uploaded a picture and refined the explanation a bit. The datetime is in the format 
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
Currently in column O

And the output goes in columns H and I
I tried modifying the previous code but I couldn't make it work...

Comment: Can you explain `Reads a value ("Date time") from a cell 2` a little more.

Comment: Of course! The process would be (simplified) like this:


1) The user writes a list of date_time values in column O, starting from row 2
2) For each of these date_times, th code searches, in the API, which objects match to each date_time value (there are no duplicates)
3) The code outputs the values for OPEN & CLOSE that correspond to each date_time values
The API is made of objects like:

{

    "DATE_TIME": "2019-04-03 00:00:00",

    "OPEN": 0.94261,

    "HIGH": 0.94262,

    "LOW": 0.94247,

    "CLOSE": 0.94247,

    "VOLUME": 6

  }

date_time values never repeat

Comment: The idea is basically, answering the questions: What was the open price at this date & time? What was the close price at that date?
And so on with a list of date_times. The value in column N also varies dynamically, so that different days fetch from different urls

Comment: Okay how do you want to initiate the search?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207869/discussion-between-cooper-and-laura-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onEdit Search**

You will need to add a column of checkboxes to column 17 and also create an installable onEdit trigger.  You may use the code provided or do it manually via the Edit/Project Triggers menu. When using the trigger creation code please check to insure that only one trigger was creates as multiple triggers can cause problems.

Also, don't make the mistake of naming your installable trigger onEdit(e) because it will respond to the simple trigger and the installable trigger causing problems.

I have an animation below showing you how it operates and also you can see the spreadsheet layout as well.  Please notice the hidden columns.  I had to do that to make the animation as small as possible. But I didn't delete any of your columns.

It's best to wait for the the check box to get reset back to off before checking another check box.  It is possible to check them so fast that script can't keep up and some searches may be missed.

I also had to add these scopes manually:

"oauthScopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]

You can put them into your appsscript.json file which is viewable using the View/Show Manifest File. Here's a [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes) that just barely shows you what they look like. But the basic idea is to put a comma after the last entry before the closing bracket and add the needed lines.

After you have created the trigger it's better to go into View/Current Project triggers and set the Notifications to Immediate.  If you get scoping errors it will tell you which ones to add.  You add them and then run a function and you can reauthorize the access with the additional scopes.  You can even run a null function like `function dummy(){};`.

This is the onEdit function:

```
function searchOnEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');// I use these lines for debugging
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='API') return;
  var checkedValue='TRUE';//these are the defaults if you install the checkboxes from the Insert Menu
  var uncheckedValue='FALSE';
  if(e.range.columnStart==17 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value==checkedValue) {
    e.range.setValue(uncheckedValue);
    //e.source.toast('flag1');
    var r=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var obj={datetime:r[14],url:r[13],event:e};//you dont really need e here
    var dObj=getDataDT1(obj);
    //Logger.log(dObj);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).setValue(dObj.OPEN);//loading OPEN on your spreadsheet
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,5).setValue(dObj.CLOSE);//loadding CLOSE on your spreadsheet
  }
}
```

This is the search function.  I tried caching the data but it was too large. So if you can reduce the size significantly that would help speed things up for consecutive searches.

```
//{datetime:'',url:'',event:e}
function getDataDT1(obj) {
  var r=UrlFetchApp.fetch(obj.url);
  var data=JSON.parse(r.getContentText("UTF-8"));
  //Logger.log(data);
  var pair='USDJPY';
  var dat=new Date(obj.datetime);
  var dtv=new Date(dat.getFullYear(),dat.getMonth(),dat.getDate(),dat.getHours(),dat.getMinutes()).valueOf();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var dt=data[i].DATE_TIME.split(' ');
    var sd=new Date(data[i].DATE_TIME);
    var sdv=new Date(sd.getFullYear(),sd.getMonth(),sd.getDate(),sd.getHours(),sd.getMinutes()).valueOf();
    if(sdv==dtv) {
      var d=dt[0].split('-');
      var t=dt[1].split(':');
      var datestring=Utilities.formatString('%s/%s/%s',d[1],d[2],d[0]);
      var timestring=Utilities.formatString('%s:%s',t[0],t[1]);
      var rObj={DATE:datestring,TIME:timestring,PAIR:pair,OPEN:data[i].OPEN.toFixed(3),CLOSE:data[i].CLOSE.toFixed(3)};
      break;
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(rObj);
  return rObj;
}
```

This is the create Trigger function.  Becareful not to run this more than once and always go check to see that there is only one and set the notifications to immediate when you first turn it on so you'll get emails pretty quickly after errors occur.

```
function createSearchOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('searchOnEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```

Animation:

[image]

This is a copy of your spreadsheet with the check boxes.

[image]

If you have any difficulties feel free to come back and get some help. I know some of this stuff sounds a bit daunting but it's kind of like going metric. Once you've measured and weighed a few things it begins to sound and feel natural.

Here's my code exactly as I have it in my script which is running right now.  Perhaps I have a typo in it due to editing in comments.  This has some debugging lines in which run the Logger and display toasts which you should probably comment out.

```
function searchOnEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='API') return;
  var checkedValue='TRUE';
  var uncheckedValue='FALSE';
  if(e.range.columnStart==17 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value==checkedValue) {
    e.range.setValue(uncheckedValue);
    e.source.toast('flag1');
    var r=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var obj={datetime:r[14],url:r[13],event:e};
    var dObj=getDataDT1(obj);
    Logger.log(dObj);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).setValue(dObj.OPEN);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,5).setValue(dObj.CLOSE);
  }
}

//{datetime:'',url:''}
function getDataDT1(obj) {
  var r=UrlFetchApp.fetch(obj.url);
  var data=JSON.parse(r.getContentText("UTF-8"));
  //Logger.log(data);
  var pair='USDJPY';
  var dat=new Date(obj.datetime);
  var dtv=new Date(dat.getFullYear(),dat.getMonth(),dat.getDate(),dat.getHours(),dat.getMinutes()).valueOf();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var dt=data[i].DATE_TIME.split(' ');
    var sd=new Date(data[i].DATE_TIME);
    var sdv=new Date(sd.getFullYear(),sd.getMonth(),sd.getDate(),sd.getHours(),sd.getMinutes()).valueOf();
    if(sdv==dtv) {
      var d=dt[0].split('-');
      var t=dt[1].split(':');
      var datestring=Utilities.formatString('%s/%s/%s',d[1],d[2],d[0]);
      var timestring=Utilities.formatString('%s:%s',t[0],t[1]);
      var rObj={DATE:datestring,TIME:timestring,PAIR:pair,OPEN:data[i].OPEN.toFixed(3),CLOSE:data[i].CLOSE.toFixed(3)};
      break;
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(rObj);
  return rObj;
}

function createSearchOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('searchOnEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```